# OleDbException (0x80004005):  Not specified error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, oledb, datareader

I created a button (`Next`) to navigate in a Table called `CHAPTERS`;

My problem is that the button work Two, and sometimes three times. After that I get [Not specified error].

This is my code :

```
Dim S As Integer = Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("id"))
Dim RQ As String
Dim DR As OleDbDataReader
RQ = "SELECT ID_C FROM CHAPTRES"
DR = Connexion.lecture(RQ)
While DR.Read
    If DR.GetInt32(0) = S Then
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

    If DR.Read = True Then
        S = DR.GetInt32(0)
        Response.Redirect("Chapitre.aspx?id=" & S)
    Else   
        // End of records (stop reading)
    End If
```

Thanks.

**`UPDATES :`**

This the `connecter` and `lecture` functions in my `Connexion.vb` file :

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Connexion

Public Shared Function conecter() As OleDbConnection
    Dim MyConnexion As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "/Learning.mdb")
    MyConnexion.Open()
    Return MyConnexion
End Function

Public Shared Function lecture(ByVal requete As String) As OleDbDataReader
    Dim Mycommand As OleDbCommand = conecter().CreateCommand()
    Mycommand.CommandText = requete
    Dim myReader As OleDbDataReader = Mycommand.ExecuteReader()
    Return myReader

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you're not closing/disposing your OleDbDataReader.  The `Response.Redirect` call takes you off to another page without closing the open data reader.

Try modifying your last chunk of code to this:

```
If DR.Read = True Then 
    S = DR.GetInt32(0) 
    DR.Close()
    DR.Dispose()
    Response.Redirect("Chapitre.aspx?id=" & S) 
Else    
    // End of records (stop reading) 
End If
```

**Update:**  It would obviously help if you provided more information, like maybe exactly what line of code in this example is throwing the exception.

Comment: @AZIRAR: you don't have to down-vote an answer just because it isn't correct. I generally reserve downvotes for grossly inaccurate answers that are liable to mislead others. In your case, you should be in the habit of closing data readers, regardless of whether this is the cause of your current problem or not.

Comment: Are you trying to read from an Access database (*.mdb) or an Excel file (*.xls)?

Comment: It looks like this error can occur as a result of a connection being left open. How does your `Connexion` object work? Does it maintain an open connection?

Comment: @MusiGenesis `this error occur as a result of a connection being left open` Thanks a lot.